# How to add two different rows with different queries in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

So let's take an example, I have a table with data
[Total Points is the sum of two points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZPoy.png)

now i have merged the rows with same name and now what i need to do is calculate the total(sum) of the two total points and display it in next row. like this
[Total of 'total points'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mROOu.png)
here is my code

```
<table>
<tr align="center">
<td>Name</td>
<td>Point1</td>
<td>Point2</td>
<td>Total Points</td>
</tr>
<?php
$select_name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_name))
{
?>
<tr align="center">
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['point1']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['point2']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['point1']+$row['point2']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>  
<tr align="center">
<td>Name</td>
<td>Point1</td>
<td>Point2</td>
<td>Total Points</td>
</tr>
<?php
$select_name = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM test");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_name))
{
$query_table1 = mysql_query("SELECT sum(point1) as sum1,sum(point2) as sum2, sum(point1)+sum(point2) as total FROM test WHERE name='".$row['name']."'");
?>
<tr align="center">
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo mysql_result($query_table1, 0, "sum1"); ?></td>
<td><?php echo mysql_result($query_table1, 0, "sum2"); ?></td>
<td><?php echo mysql_result($query_table1, 0, "total"); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr align="center">
<td>Total</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>???</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always separate your PHP logic from your HTML. It will allow you to write code more powerful, more flexible and much easier to debug.

Do your queries and calculations entirely in PHP, until you've built up the rows as arrays. AFterwards, you should have something like:

```
$tbl_1 = [
    ['abc',20,21,41], ['abc',25,14,39],
    ['def',22,27,49], ['def',23,18,41]
];
```

You don't even need a 2nd query because you already have all the data. Just manipulate it in PHP to get the statistics you need and put them in a 2nd array:

```
$tbl_2 = [
    ['abc',45,35,80], ['def',45,45,90]
];
```

To find the grand-total, you could loop through the 3rd column of either array.

Only once you have all done all your logic, should you move on to HTML and display the results.